# Design for the future or make it tightly coupled to the implementation

Tags: design-patterns, architectural-patterns, swift-language

My question is regarding how would the developer know when you add interfaces/protocols to their code and inject them as dependency.

Consider an example of BudgetService.

```
protocol BudgetServiceProtocol {
    func save(name: String, amount: Double) throws
}

class BudgetService: BudgetServiceProtocol {
    
    private let viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    
    init(viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.viewContext = viewContext
    }
    
    func save(name: String, amount: Double) throws {
        
        let budget = Budget(context: viewContext)
        budget.name = name
        budget.amount = amount
        try viewContext.save()
    }
    
}
```

BudgetService is injected into the ContentView.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let budgetService: BudgetServiceProtocol
    // other code 
}

@main
struct BudgetAppApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(budgetService: BudgetService(viewContext: CoreDataProvider.shared.viewContext))
            
        }
    }
}
```

My question is that if I have a single concrete implementation of BudgetService then should I even make a protocol. Also, I will be using the real BudgetService implementation to run the tests so this means I will not be creating mocks etc. Would it make sense to change the ContentView implementation to use BudgetService concrete implementation.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let budgetService = BudgetService()
```

}

```
class BudgetService {
    
    private let viewContext = CoreDataProvider.shared.viewContext
```

I am a painting myself to the corner by coupling my ContentView with the concrete implementation of the BudgetService, even though I know that there will not be any other BudgetService.

OR

Should I play defense and create all the abstractions so maybe I can change it easily in the future?

Comment: Which language is this, Swift? Programming patterns sometimes vary by language.

Comment: Yes. This is Swift.

Comment: not a full answer, but I like the Rule of Three: once you have three similar versions of a thing then it makes sense to have an abstraction instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependency injection helps code reuse, and unit tests are often one kind of code reuse you need. But if you can test the real deal without needing to inject a mock, then you don't really need the DI, either.

You can always go in after-the-fact and extract interface when you need it.